# I am having troubles on the process of implementing generic binary search tree

Tags: java, string, generics, binary-search-tree

Let's say that the data type I insert into BST is TypeT.
I want to create a BST that can works similarly with either String and Integer data types.
I tried to convert TypeT into String and then I used compareTo method in the String class.

But compareTo method doesn't works as I expected for example;

When I run this line  --->
System.out.println("5".compareTo("10"));

It outputs 4,what I was expecting was -1 because 5<10

Comment: "I want to create a BST that can works similarly with either String and Integer data types" Then you shouldn't convert everything to String. Using `String.compareTo` with on integers is not going to work. How about constraining `T` to `Comparable<T>`? Can you show the definition of the BST class and where you are using `compareTo`?

Comment: And for your question, yes compareTo returns positive and negative values during comparison (not just bounded by -1 to +1). When you compare two char sequence their char values are tested. 5 -> 53, 1-> 49 and hence their diff will be 4

Comment: Thanks for the answers.I must work on OOP principles before trying to implement BST.